# Using arrays to make a study room reservation program

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program in C that will give users a menu to reserve a study room.
1. Reserve a room
2. Vacate room
3. Show available rooms
4. exit
There are 10 total rooms. I'm not sure how to use change values in an array where 0 == room open and 1 == room closed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_arr(int room[], int elements);
int search_arr(int room[], int elements, int open);

int main(void)
{
    int room[10] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 }; // array for 10 rooms
    int result, open;

    print_arr(room, 10);

    open = 0;

    result = search_arr(room, 10, open);

    if (result == -1)
        printf("There are no open rooms. \n");
    else 
        printf("There are %d vacant Rooms. ", result);

return 0;
}

void print_arr(int room[], int elements)
{
    int i;

    printf("Rooms: ");
    for (i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", room[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int search_arr(int room[], int elements, int open)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        if (room[i] == open)

            printf("Vacant Room: %d \n", room[i]);
            return(open);   //found open rooms
    }
return(-1); //no open rooms found
}
```

Comment: To change the first room to be open, you would assign `room[0]=0;`, for example.

Comment: Some proper indentation would help. The if in `search_arr` looks like it's not doing what you want it to do.

Comment: My print statement that says "There are %d vacant Rooms." always says 0. How do I get it to give the number of 0's in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to count the number of free (open) rooms in the array, e.g.:

```
int search_arr(int room[], int elements, int open)
{
 int free = 0;
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < elements; i++)
 {
    if (room[i] == open) {
        printf("Vacant Room number: %d \n", i);
        free++;
    }
 }
 return(free); // return number of vacant rooms; 0 if no rooms are free ;-)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search routine is returning 0 (which is the value of open) in every case, and it does so on the first room found that is open.  To count the open rooms, you can't return until you've seen every element, and you have to increment a counter each time you see a room that is "open".

```
int search_arr(int room[], int elements, int open)
{
  int i, openrooms=0;

  for (i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    if (room[i] == open)
      openrooms++;

  return openrooms; // returns 0 when none found...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic used in `search_arr` function is wrong. It should be-

```
int search_arr(int room[], int elements, int open)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        if (room[i] == 0)

            {printf("Vacant Room No: %d \n", i);
            open++; //found open rooms
    }} if(open)
return(open);
return(-1); //no open rooms found
}
```